# Do transfering steam games to another computer reset that game's save data?

Tags: steam

I have a steam account and I want to transfer some games to my laptop. I was just wondering if I transfer the games to my laptop, would it reset the data?

Answer (score 6):

If you have Steam Cloud synchronization enabled, any applicable games will back up their saves to the cloud so you can access them from whatever device you install the game on.

To make sure this option is turned on:

1. Open Steam
2. In the top right, click *Steam*, then click *Settings*.
3. Click *Cloud* on the left hand list.
4. Make sure **Enable Steam Cloud synchronization for applications which support it** is checked.

You should be good to go after this! Note that some games might not be compatible with Steam's cloud support, but most modern games should be.

Comment: It's worth asking permission to do this if you're playing on someone else's account, they may want their saves backed up.

Answer (score 3):

Some games use the Steam cloud sync as Kaizerwolf wrote, some don't

In addition enabling Steam Cloud Sync, you could potentially copy over most of them yourself.

A lot of games store their saves under

```
C:\Users\<Username>\Documents\My Games
```

If you copy this entire directory over (or individually for saves that you're missing), you'll be able to ensure most of your saves are moved across.

Comment: Very true, I had meant to add this as well!

Comment: Game save location are entirely up to the developer.  I've seen enough in AppData also.

Comment: @Nelson - True, but it comes down to semantics. 'Appdata' is meant for any configuration files etc that your program needs. 'Documents' is meant for any user-created files. Technically speaking, Saves are user-created files, but I can see how some devs would do otherwise (for example, games where you don't implicitly save, or the 'real' save is not meant to be edited or copied, especially online profiles and the such)

Comment: There is no guaranteed rule to find save files.  Just Google the specific game.